# sending list of values in JSONObject

Tags: java, json

```
public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try {


            inputJsonObj.put("ipaddress","10.254.27.12");

            inputJsonObj.put("ipaddress", "10.253.140.116");


            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://10.85.249.29:8080/checkRest/CheckxARC/getVersion");
//             

            ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, inputJsonObj.toString());
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println(" op--->"+output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have created a client side code for calling restful webservices. Previously when I was sending single ipaddress it was working perfectly.Now when i am trying to send more than 1 IPadrresses I am being able to proceed.Can anyone suggest me how can I proceed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a [JSONArray](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html). In it, you will store all your ip adress.

Then, you add the array to your JSONObject using the put method.

It would look like:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("10.254.27.12");
array.put("10.254.27.123");

JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
inputJsonObj.put("ipaddresses",array);
// Using ipaddresses as there are many addresses
// The rest of the code stays the same
```

*Note: sorry, I did not add much time to test it, but the logic and objects are there. :)*

Cheers

Comment: Can u help me like I am been able to get two  get two ip address and send.Now I am not been able to recieve the ip separtely in the calling function.How can I proceed on that?

Comment: Hello riza, you can use [obj.getJsonArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonArray-java.lang.String-) on your output. From there, you have a JSONArray that you can browse. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add an integer value to the key stored for that value? Then at the receiving end just write something to loop through and get all values Example:

```
  public class sample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
            try {

                inputJsonObj.put("ipaddress","10.254.27.12");
                inputJsonObj.put("ipaddress1", "10.253.140.116"); // Add one to the name

                Client client = Client.create();
                WebResource webResource = client
                        .resource("http://10.85.249.29:8080/checkRest/CheckxARC/getVersion");            

                ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                        .post(ClientResponse.class, inputJsonObj.toString());
                String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

                System.out.println(" op--->"+output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**Get all IP addresses:**

```
    Collection values = jObject.values();
    values.forEach( System.out::print );
```

Edited errors in code.

Comment: What you do with the values stored inside the collection is up to you, in this example I am simply printing them out to the console.